# About tail distribution of a sum

Tags: random-variable, exponential-distribution, probability-inequalities, bounds

Do we know anything about the tail distribution of sum of squares of a limited number of i.i.d exponentially distributed random variables? I'm looking for a good bound.

Comment: The square of an exponential r.v. is [Weibull with shape parameter $1/2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution#Related_distributions). Its convolution with itself is not analytically tractable, but the convolutions can be done numerically. But I expect you knew this.

Comment: Some possible references: (1) F. Yilmaz and M. Alouini (2009), *Sum of Weibull Variates and Performance of Diversity Systems*, IWCMC 2009, p247-252 **and** (2)
Filho, J.C.S.S., Yacoub, M.D. (2006), *Simple precise approximations to Weibull sums*, Communications Letters, IEEE

Comment: I'm not sure about the fact that the square of an exponential is Weibull? and I cannot find any reference about that.

Comment: Vadim, you can find a reference at the link @Glen_b provided. :-) it would help to know (quantitatively) what kind of a bound you are seeking. (What are you hoping to show?)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution#cite_note-JKB-2 is the reference for the place in wikipedia I linked to earlier that includes a more general statement, of which my first comment is a special case.