# Tail distribution of sum of Weibull distributed variables

Tags: distributions, approximation, weibull-distribution

Is there a bound on the tail distribution of a finite sum of i.i.d Weibull random variables?

Comment: You'll need to be more precise about "nice", I think.

Comment: I may say "any" bound! actually I need a bound in terms of number of random variables contributing in the sum. Like what we have in other tail distributions, typically an exponential bound or something like that. These types of RV are frequently seen in wireless systems and etc. but I can't use methods in my level. As much as I know we can not use Chernoff bound since it does not have    moment generating function. I do not know about any other methods.

Comment: Have you tried the Hölder inequality?

Comment: I need an exponential bound. I don't think that helps

Comment: There are some references and comments that might be of some help in [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45410/about-tail-distribution-of-a-sum)

Comment: Glen_b's reference sounds promising, but the Hölder inequality lets you relate the sum of Weibull random variables with shape $k \gt 1$ to the sum of exponential random variables, for which you have exponential bounds http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4816/what-are-the-sharpest-known-tail-bounds-for-chi-k2-distributed-variables. For $k \lt 1$, you can't get exponential bounds because the tail of each term decays too slowly.

Comment: By the way, there is a vote to close this as an exact duplicate of a past question, which essentially asks for a tail bound for $k=1/2$. However, I don't agree that this is an exact duplicate because $k=1/2$ was not specified here, and seems counter-indicated by the request for exponential bounds which are impossible for $k=1/2$.

Comment: When the shape is $<1$, the distribution can be shown to be *subexponential* as defined in the book 
'Modelling Extremal Events for Insurance and Finance'
by Embrechts , Klüppelberg and Mikosch (chap 1). This means that the survival $S(x)$ of the convolution is equivalent to the survival of the max of the same number of i.i.d. variables for large $x$. Not a bound yet.

Comment: Do you need a bound or can you use an approximation, such as the saddlepoint aproximation, which can be very good?

Comment: Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution  you can find expressions for the moment generating function. They might be difficult to use, though.

Answer (score 1):

The convolution form is not closed, so it is impossible to do in the continuos way. You can use a Taylor Series Sum instead to approach the convolution.
If you're not looking for a nice solution, and want to be more practical, try doing simple simulation and choose a nice fit.

Answer (score 0):

For the asymptotic tail, search for "sub-Weibull" distributions. They develop concentration properties in a similar manner we cope with sub-exponentials or sub-gaussians.